Can I checkout an unfetched remote git branch, with a single command?
A very popular question here on SO is:
How do I check out a remote Git branch?
but the answers there either assume the branch-of-interest is already fetched, or suggest that we git fetch first.
My question: Is it possible to checkout a remote branch which has not yet been fetched, with a single git command?
Note: You may assume as new a version of git as you like, if it matters.

Why would you like it as a single git command?

Because it is a single command - in English: "Please check out branch foo from remote bar". There is no information that I need from the fetch, so git shouldn't need it either before taking that command from me.

Your "no fetch" constraint seems arbitrary. Why is it a problem? How do you expect your machine to read distant data without said data being transported over network at some point? Are you searching for alternatives to git protocol?

Your explanation about it being a single step "in english" is technically irrelevant. Compare with someone asking "Please write function X to add two variables". There is no information that I need to type characters, so my IDE shouldn't need it either. (Not trying to be the snark knight here, just desperately trying to understand your odd question setting)

@RomainValeri: By your logic, we shouldn't have a command for creating a branch and switching to it, either. "Why is it a problem" to first create the branch, then switch to it?

Atomic commands are useful, and composite commands are also useful. But ignoring the underlying steps doesn't magically make them unexist. If your local machine needs to display some data, this data has to come accross the network at some point, in some way. If you're asking if there's a composite command to combine fetching and checking out, I don't find that absurd at all, yes it could be useful, but no it doesn't exist as such. Aliases are here to do this sort of small command grouping.

Agree with Romain here. You are asserting statements that aren't correct and trying to pass opinions as facts. "Because its a signle command" no its not. Git operates on local knowledge of remote branches. Checking out a remote branch requires two operations, one to fetch the reference and another to switch to the branch. Your opinion that this should be a single command is irrelevant when discussing git because that's not how git is implemented

@AliRaza: "no its not" <- perhaps you should read the rest of my sentence. "Git operates on local knowledge of remote branches" <- I'm giving it the knowledge it needs, which is: the name of a branch on the remote. It does not need further knowledge in order to fetch that branch and check it out. Anyway, if you're certain git won't do that, then write an answer saying "No, it's not possible". It's as good an answer as any, if that's actually the case.

Sorry, I thought that was already established. It is not possible, there is no way of doing this.

@einpoklum So far as I know, there is no shortcut command that combines git fetch + git checkout/switch yet. We can create and checkout a branch without git fetch, but the branch may not point at the right commit. I asked because I want to know your initial motivation to this question. You may think a single command could solve your problem. I want to make it clear and maybe find another solution.

@ElpieKay: I'm not sure how I could further explain my initial motivation... it seems intuitive to me that if I tell git about a remote branch that I want to checkout, and it does not yet know about that branch, it will interpret my request as also indicating it should fetch information about that branch from the remote.

@einpoklum “ it will interpret my request as also indicating it should fetch...” Meaning that git-checkout(1) would do a fetch to check if mian is in origin now when I misstype main?

@Guildenstern: Yes, exactly. Just like if you were to mistype mian instead of main if you did that using two commands...

@einpoklum I wouldn’t expect Git to ever do a network call on git-checkout(1) just-in-case there was something on some remote unless I’m working in a shallow checkout or other such on-demand modes.

@Guildenstern: This would be exactly the same as if you had run something like git fetch origin mian; git checkout origin/mian.

@einpoklum The one provided in the only answer so far, which you criticized as not really being a single command, but nonetheless a “decent hack I suppose”.

@Guildenstern: "The one" what? I'm not following.

The same command as in the only answer so far

@Guildenstern: You mean the two-command alias? Ok, what about it?

If you don't have the branch fetched at all, you could create an alias. In ~/.gitconfig:
[alias]
    checkout-with-fetch = "!f() { git fetch origin $1 >/dev/null && git checkout -b $1 origin/$1 }; f"

This will run a git fetch, but at least you get the illusion that it didn't... however I wouldn't recommend overwriting git commit as this is bound to cause you to unintentionally lose some work later on.

So, that's not really a single git command, and will obviously not work on systems other than my own, but - it's a decent hack I suppose.

@einpoklum I don’t understand why it needs to be a single existing Git command. Commands are made to be composed.

@Guildenstern: 1. Because other "single" commands are already "composite", like creating a new branch + checking it out, or even create + set-remote + checkout. 2. Because it sounds like a single command in English. 3. Because composition complicates things, requiring either more typing or setting state, like the alias you offered.

I think the alias is missing at least one semicolon
